# php - constructor of parent class is not being invoked from child class

Tags: php, class, oop

parent class:

```
<?php

class Emailer {

    protected $sender;
    private $recipients;
    private $subject;
    private $body;

    function __construct($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->recipients = array();
    }

    public function addRecipients($recipient)
    {
        array_push($this->recipients, $recipient);
    }

    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        foreach($this->recipients as $recipient)
        {
            $result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body, "From: {$this->sender}\r\n");
            if($result)
                echo "Mail successfully sent to {$recipient}" . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

child class:

```
<?php

class ExtendedEmailer extends Emailer {

    function __construct() {}

    public function setSender($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }
}
```

Now I am doing this

```
include_once("classes/class.emailer.php");
include_once("classes/class.extendedemailer.php");
$xemailer = new ExtendedEmailer();
$xemailer->setSender("someone@example.com");
$xemailer->addRecipients("person1@example.com");
$xemailer->setSubject("Just a Test");
$xemailer->setBody("Hi person1, How are you?");
$xemailer->sendEmail();
```

but this gives me the following errors...

`Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\classes\class.emailer.php on line 19`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\classes\class.emailer.php on line 34`

but when I move the line `$this->recipients = array();` inside the scope of `addRecipient` method it works. That means the constructor of the parent class is not invoked. The concept is to initialize the `$recipient` variable with an empty array when any object is created. Is it the normal behaviour or not.

modified parent class:

```
<?php

class Emailer {

    protected $sender;
    private $recipients;
    private $subject;
    private $body;

    function __construct($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    public function addRecipients($recipient)
    {
        $this->recipients = array();
        array_push($this->recipients, $recipient);
    }

    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        foreach($this->recipients as $recipient)
        {
            $result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body, "From: {$this->sender}\r\n");
            if($result)
                echo "Mail successfully sent to {$recipient}" . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following output:

`Mail successfully sent to person1@example.com`

And what I am actually trying to do is learning how to access a protected property of a parent class from a child class. Which is `$sender` in this case.

Comment: You should call your parent's constructor explicitly with `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `parent::__construct();`  in child constructor

```
class ExtendedEmailer extends Emailer {

       function __construct($sender)
        {
           parent::__construct($sender);
        }

        public function setSender($sender)
        {
            $this->sender = $sender;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in that case the constructor of my parent class accepts an argument which is `$sender`. So should I pass it whil creating object of the child class or just make it `NULL` in the constructor of the parent class then set it by calling the `setSender` method from the child class ?? @Rex Rex